# Deleting a tuple from Database

Tags: android-sqlite

In my app there is an button. when pressed user framelayout is added which contains textview and a samll delete button. So whenever user presses that delete button that tuple should get deleted from database. but i m facing problem in this. by pressing delete button how it will come to know which instance is to be passed to delete funtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are adding new view, you can set id (or any other object) as value of to this view using setTag()

```
btn.setTag(itemId);
```

Then when you click on this button, just get tag back, and use it:

```
listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        deleteById(v.getTag());
    }
};
```

Read more about setTag in Android's API.